# Odoo Warning - Validation Error

Tags: validation, warnings, odoo

I've just installed **odoo v9** on my Ubuntu server. It seems OK but if I update quantity on hand in product, it gives me this error. Can anyone help me resolve this?

> The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
>
> - deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
> - creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
>
> [object with reference: weight_uom_id - weight.uom.id]

Answer (score 0):

Odoo is saying about you should reference this product to some UoM (Unit of Measure) record. If you don't have any (UoM), create one and then try it again.